# How to refresh all my browser pages from all the opened tabs at the same time?

Tags: browser

If I press <kbd>F5</kbd> on any web browser(Internet Explorer, Firefox or Chrome) it will refresh the current page on the current tab context. Assuming that I want to refresh all opened webpages on all the opened tabs(5 tabs for example), there is any keyboard shortcut or any another method(that not manually one by one) to do that?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and IE  have a reload all tabs option as part of the right click context menu when you rightclick on tabs, but no keyboard shortcut.

Chrome doesn't have it at all, least on my copy of canary but there's an extension that seems to be able to do it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/midkcinmplflbiflboepnahkboeonkam/details) called reload all tabs. Dosen't seem to have been updated recently however

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer, you can do this with the keyboard, but it requires more than a single keystroke.  I do this regularly, and even though it's several keystrokes, to me, it's still better than using the mouse to right-click. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>. (Note that this assumes your tabs are on the same row as your address bar.)  If you have the menu key on your keyboard, you can use that instead of the <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>.